Can we ban certain user or warn them by e-mail.?
User 1633 "Dail" I believe has been quite active recently on the site, but he doesn't not seem to be willing to understand our rules and the way we work.
According to his profile, he asked 10 questions, accepted no answers, and has seen 5 questions closed.
Today, first thing in the morning, I need to close a question which doesn't make sense and has been asked 3 times in his own different post (sometimes closed).
Do we have to keep closing the questions or can a mod do something about it.
I believe there should be a mechanism which prevents users having had 3 questions closed recently from reposting within a week or something like that.

You may recall that I deleted the account of someone who clearly didn't belong here. He just created a new account and bitched about his "mistreatment". I wasn't at all concerned that he felt he was being treated unfairly, but I did want to restore his favorites since he apparently was using the links for research (as dubious as that is).
Supposedly the protocol is for the moderator to warn the user directly and then suspend the account. I'll give that a try this time and see what happens.

okay because I even flagged some of his comment which were in my opinion quite offensive he was told his question was unclear.

I think user 909 could use a similar time out.

I would agree that Dail's questions and comments have been annoying, off-topic, and difficult to understand, but he seems to be suffering more from stupidity and obstinacy than ill will towards the site.  The issue, then, is more about setting a proper required level of intelligence and intelligibility.  I would agree Dail does not meet what should be our standards, and chris's move to suspend seems appropriate.  Perhaps in the future he will get the point and will simply take some more time to think before posting unintelligible half-formed thoughts as "questions."

I know this is a question and answer site and that this idea may not be in the spirit of stackexchange but I would like to propose it anyways:
Can we have a reputation threshold (> 101) for asking questions? This would eliminate most of these annoying questions.

Hmmm. You'd'previously have to gather rep by answering. I beleive it would reduce de number of new users regardless their quality.

Our threshold is pretty simple: Anyone who wants to post on this site must be a quant, either in grad school or by profession. Unfortunately, the "Ask Question" function doesn't prompt users beforehand to verify that they truly have a career in this field.
